# What does "so" refer to

Tags: pronouns

> A survey by Barna research group found the top reason given by Americans for the fake news phenomenon is "reader error," **more so than** made-up stories or factual mistakes in reporting.

https://www.businessinsider.com/fake-news-literacy-americans-2017-5

Questions:

I don't understand the construction of this sentence."So" is a pro-form. What does it refer to?  Is it "reader error"？ But usually "so" refers to a thing, not a noun.

Is "more... than..." in the same use as:

> He is more old than middle aged.

Comment: Quick net search found this.   https://grammarist.com/usage/moreso/

Comment: more so than is the same as more than. It's idiomatic and somewhat informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right "so" is a proform. In this case, it's an adverbial recalling the adjective "top", which roughly acts as a superlative for "common". So the meaning is:

> ... the top reason given by Americans for the fake news phenomenon is "reader error," **which is more common** than made-up stories or factual mistakes in reporting.